# Java: Short form to create an instance of a class that implements an interface

Tags: java, new-operator, implements

I'd like to use the `new` operator to create an instance of `JPanel` that implements `ActionListener` and directly overrides the `actionPerformed` method.

I tried

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel implements ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

but that doesn't work because of a syntax error.

Of course I could just define a new class like `JPanelWithActionListener` and call this one with `new`, but is there any way to do it in just one line?

Comment: No, you need to have a (super) type to implement. In your case you'd need to define some kind of class/interface that inherits both `JPanel` and `ActionListener`. But if you already have it, I suggest to not use an anonymous inner class.

Comment: It's usually a questionable approach to have a panel implement `ActionListener` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in Java - there is no anonymous type in Java.

Your code `new JPanel implements ActionListener() { /*...*/ };` is equivalent to this code.

```
class JPanelWithActionListener extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
JPanel panle = new JPanelWithActionListener();
```

You want to create a new type `JPanelWithActionListener` without defining a class (so, that class is anonymous).